# Automatic build succeed even though UT fails in Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online)

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I'm publishing a web solution which includes both server side(C#) and client side(JavaScript) UTs.

When a C# UT fails the entire build fails as expected. However, when a JS UT fails the build is marked "successful". How can I configure the build to fails when a JS UT fails?

Comment: Help me out, what's a UT?

Comment: Duh, might want to spell that out at least once so it's more clear to everyone.  Also might want to include what technology you're using to run your JS UTs.

Comment: I'm using Jasmine to run my JS UTs